# Parameter validation, or let it fail?

Tags: c#

**Aprroach 1:**

```
public static void SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
{
   if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(from))
      throw new ArgumentNullOrWhiteSpaceException("from");

   if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(to))
      throw new ArgumentNullOrWhiteSpaceException("to");

   var msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body) { IsBodyHtml = true };

   using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
      smtp.Send(msg);
}
```

---

**Approach 2:**

```
public static void SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
{
   var msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body) { IsBodyHtml = true };

   using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
      smtp.Send(msg);
}
```

---

Why would I validate the parameters in approach 1, and not just wait for `MailMessage` to throw an exception (approach 2), telling me that I have passed a empty `from` or `to` value, to the constructor?

So why would I throw my own exception?

Comment: Your function seems to be a trivial wrapper around an existing constructor with the same parameter names. In most cases, there's some transformation between the passed parameters and any inner function/method calls. Your caller might not understand an exception complaining about parameter `bar` when they only passed a parameter `foo`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1102113/393487

Comment: I believe "why would I throw my own exception?" is a question you should be asking yourself. If YOU don't see the reason, why do it? Anyway the MailMessage constructor will throw exceptions telling you the same things those custom exceptions do, so in this case it's not necessary to have them, but it's a different matter in more sophisticated cases, where you want to know what is going on in greater detail.

Comment: @peer, That question is really not related to mine. The question you link to is about the best way to _check_ the parameters of the method. My question is about _when_ to check the parameters, and _when_ to let the default exception(s) occur.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Isn't that the purpose of stack trace?

Comment: A stack trace would tell you that method `PassMeFoo` called method `PassMeBar` - it won't tell you that `PassMeFoo` passed it's `foo` parameter as the `bar` parameter to `PassMeBar`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is quite simple - it makes it easier to debug.

For any given method (and this is truer of more complex methods) that requires a non-null parameter, it's going to be much easier for someone debugging an exception scenario to see an explicit exception from `SendMail` saying, "hey, 'from' is null; I need it not to be," than it is to have some method call within `SendMail` (or even some nested method call within that) throw a NullReferenceException (which, ultimately, is what will happen if none of the methods in question perform null checks).

Then, you have the scenario whereby - 6 months down the line - you decide that `SendMail` needs to do something else; e.g. (as a trivial example) set some kind of audit flag in a database. Now, if you just let the method fall over, you have an invalid flag (or you may do, depending on the order of things inside your method). Much better to say "actually, if my parameters are invalid, just fail immediately," rather than let the method carry on and have potential side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think that throwing your own exception is justified when you can give more relevant information than the function you're calling can (either to handle a more specifix exception in your code or to return a better error message to the user).

In this case it seems that you wouldn't add any information that `Send()` couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

smtp.SendMail will throw an InvalidOperationException (in the system namespace)

In this you are throwing a more suitable exception type, from the type type it easier to understand and catch the exception. InvalidOperationException is a very general class. By throwing your own exception the code is more readable and the same exception can be handled even if you change the method at a later point, for example by using another mailclient.

Answer (score 0):

erm... are you SURE in 100% that `var msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body) { IsBodyHtml = true };`

will throw those exceptions?  approach 2 is 
**undefined behavior**. how should this be unit tested?

what does SendMail("","","") do? extacly? its not clear from the second approach.

you COULD add a comment. but WHY? thats not [clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

arroach 1 clearly defines where the function is going to fail. and how it is going to handle failures. your code should make clear what is does, not comments.

P.S.

throw new `ArgumentNullOrWhiteSpaceException("from")`; is throwed in your SendMail function, closest to the source of the problem.

if you use approach 2 only god knows how deep in your call hirerchy it will be caught if at all.

also you could improve this by writting somethinf like:

`ArgumentNullOrWhiteSpaceException("from - this is usually caused if poo is not bared by poo in goo")`; ` that could simplify your life a few month later.